# Best way to minimize ice damage to a fully tiled pool?

Tags: forces, particle-physics

I am a pool builder in Massachusetts and we have started to build small, fully tiled pools and hot tubs (less than 200 sq' in area).  These units will be designed to be used over the winter, however, many of them will be winterized and covered.  This type of pool/hot tub is rarely seen in our region so I don't have a good history of how they will hold up with our freeze/thaw cycle.  In order to minimize any potential damage to the tiles from ice, I was thinking a simple de-icer (like what is used in koy ponds) would prevent the ice from fully forming during the cold winter months.  My question is whether an area in the middle of the small pool/hot tub that is not frozen would, in fact, prevent the remaining ice from exerting too much pressure on the tile and pool/hot tub walls?  Another thought would be to weigh down a few rubber boat bumpers in the pool to take the pressure from the ice.  Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Notice that a question like yours is more suitable for other SE sites.